# Difference between Running Jmeter with one user(along with 10 login data on CSV file) and 10 users on one thread group?

Tags: jmeter

Can anyone help me on, the difference between Running Jmeter with one user on one thread group(along with 10 user logins on CSV data) and 10 users on one tread group?

Answer (score 0):

- One user on one thread group

  - with loop count of 1

    - Will send one set of request from your Test Plan (Requests/Samples in your testplan will be executed serially)
  - with loop count of n

    - Will send N set of requests from your Test Plan, one after another
- 10 users on one thread group

  - with loop count of 1

    - Will start 10 parallel threads and start sending requests from your Test Plan (Request in one thread will be executed serially)